# Intercept a function call angularjs factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to intercept a function call from GTM through the angularjs factory.

I was able to do this for changing a variable: angular.element(document.querySelector('div.os-reg-form__mentor-row')).scope().$watch('registrationService.userID', function(uID){}) ;

But to call the function, watch works only once (which is logical, but the function does not change).

How can i watch up a call?

Sample:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="javaScript">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Call AngularJS function using JavaScript</title>
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var serviceModule = angular.module('javaScript', []);
    
    serviceModule.controller('javaScriptController', function($scope) {

        $scope.javaScriptCallAngular = function(value) {
            $scope.usersName = value;
            return $scope.usersName;
        };

        $scope.javaScriptCallAngularJS = function(value) {
            $scope.usersName = "Java Honk"+Math.random(0,1000);
        };
    
    });
    
    function javaScriptCall(value){
        var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('idForJS')).scope();
        scope.$watch('javaScriptController.javaScriptCallAngularJS', function(old,v_new){
            my();
        });
    }

    function my(){
        alert('1')
    }
    
</script>
</head>
<body id="idForJS" data-ng-controller="javaScriptController">


    <h2>Click below to get User Name:</h2>
    <div>
        <button onclick="javaScriptCall('Java Honk')">SET WATCH</button>
        <button data-ng-click="javaScriptCallAngularJS()">Call function</button>

        <div>User Name: {{usersName}}</div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I need my function "my()" to work all the time when calling javaScriptCallAngularJS